# How to push to an array in JSON file with typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

I am facing an issue. I want to create a function that will push into a JSON file. I am facing two situations:

1. The JSON is empty, it contains nothing, no empty array, not any character
2. The JSON already have an array.

What i done so far:

- I Checked if the result is a string and is empty (if the JSON have nothing so far), and created a new array where I pushed the instance of the class. Than write the file with the array.
- Than, in the second statement i checked if the file is a string but have something inside, parsed it, pushed new instance and than write the file again.

However, if I want to write multiple things there I get aloot of arrays of objects...

```
    public async createCategory() {
        try {
            const fileOperations = new FileSystem();
            let stateOfFile = await fileOperations.ReadFile(PathFile.Categories);
            let tempArray: Category[] = [];

            if (stateOfFile.length === 0 && typeof stateOfFile === 'string') {
                tempArray.push(this);
                await fileOperations.WriteToFile(PathFile.Categories, tempArray);
                return
            }

            else if (stateOfFile.length !== 0 && typeof stateOfFile === 'string') {
                tempArray = JSON.parse(stateOfFile);
                tempArray.push(this);
                await fileOperations.WriteToFile(PathFile.Categories, tempArray);
            }
            
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

The result :

```
[{"title":"New title","description":"This is a test","categoryId":"276d8416-68a8-47ed-8ebf-fd3addc15ab3"}]

[{"title":"New title","description":"This is a test","categoryId":"276d8416-68a8-47ed-8ebf-fd3addc15ab3"},
{"title":"New title","description":"This is a test","categoryId":"fb32d3f8-7fcc-488a-9445-de97b99773a8"}]
```

How I used this:

```
        const  cat = new Category('New title', 'This is a test');
        const  cat22 = new Category('New titlesss', 'This is a test new testing file');
        await cat.createCategory()
        await cat22.createCategory()
```

UPDATE: the WriteToFile method

```
/**
     * @param filePath  { enum } this is preset in the File system class
     * @param payload   { any } this will be stringfied in the method
     */
    async WriteToFile(filePath: PathFile, payload: any) {
        try {
                // Check the filepath argument
            this.CheckArgumentPathIsCorrect(filePath);

            const fileBuildJoin = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'database', filePath);
            const writeToFile = promisify(fs.appendFile);

            let stringfiedPayload: string;
            if (typeof payload === 'object') {
                stringfiedPayload = JSON.stringify(payload);
            }
            else if ((typeof payload === 'string')) {
                stringfiedPayload = payload;
            }
            else {
                throw new Error('Invalid payload type');
            }

            await writeToFile(fileBuildJoin, stringfiedPayload);
            return 'Success';
            
        } 
        
        catch (error) {
            this.ErrorHandlingAsync(error as Error, 'Error caught in writing file');
        }
```

Comment: Does `fileOperations.WriteToFile` overwrite the entire file or append to the existing one?

Comment: I would like to append. In the `WriteToFile(PathFile.Categories, tempArray)` method I used append method.

Comment: I updated the file. I added the WriteTofile method

Comment: I think you will need to overwrite the whole file.  Say you have a json file containing `{"name":"bob"}` - appending any text to that results in invalid json.  You would need to insert your new data inside that structure not at the end.

Comment: Does it worth it to add a new boolean param and overwrite to the same function? or I will add too much complexities?

Comment: Overwrite worked. But should this be used when writing blogs? In this situation I only create small object. But the next functionalities will be to create MDX files and write/retrieve data. Is overwriting a solution?

Comment: @danielsas no definitely not. There's a big difference between a file that *is* a JSON file and a file that *contains some* JSON data somewhere in it. You are not going to be able to easily programmatically deal with a file that has irregular contents including JSON that might be in it somewhere like a markdown file. Can't you import JSON in MDX with webpack et. al.? If so that would solve your problem since you can just read/write the valid JSON to the .json files and import them in your markdown.

Comment: Aaaa. Thank you. My goal is to keep the categories file as json because I want to iterate over, and the MDX files that will have the content will have as title the category id (to be identified quickly). Than, the content of mdx will contain some rich text format...